# List comprehension if based logic

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

In the following code, strike is a double and right is either 'C' or 'P'. How do I modify this statement so that only [adouble is some random double]

For example, rights = ['P', 'C'], chain.strikes = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] and adouble is say 50. So I want only those 'C' that are greater than adouble (50) and only those 'P' that are less than adouble (50). Right now, I am getting all of them.

```
strikes > adouble if right == 'C' or strikes < adouble if right == 'P'
```

In other words, I only want to add to contracts Out of the Money Calls and Out of the Money Puts:

```
contracts = [Option(symbol, expiration, strike, right, 'SMART')
        for right in rights
        for expiration in expirations
        for strike in chain.strikes]
```

Comment: You are doing a greater than, less than check. Place the double value in place of all `adouble`. `||` should be `or`. I didn't get the second part of your question. How is that related to the first snippet!?

Comment: The important part is the second part. In other words, when doing contracts =, how do I restrict the list to only those values in the if statement?

Comment: Give a concrete example for better understanding

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want an `if` in a comprehension as a filter, you should code it at the end.

Comment: Give an input and expected output example.

Comment: See edited post for clarification

Comment: I actually don't care if I have to do another pass and remove all those Option from contracts where the right is a 'C' and the strike < adouble, and the right is a 'P', and the strike > adouble